# Total system failure on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: performance, data-recovery

I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre that just had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it. I installed restricted extras, attempted to turn on the firewall in the terminal, and made a few extra tweaks. Now there is a ghost in my machine. For some reason, I have no control over the mouse, it opens pages and documents on it's own, and there are ghosts in my screen.

My question is this: Is there an easy way to reconfigure Ubuntu 14.04 back to when it was freshly installed? I'd like to have a do over! Also, I spilled a glass of water on the router, but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Best way is to reinstall ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Maybe the glass of what does have something to do with it. I had similar behaviour once after spilling water over the keyboard. The best way to rule that out is by unplugging mouse, keyboard and network cable.

Comment: Does this behaviour only happen with your user account or also with others?